# ClimbingLeaderboard function on Hackerrank not working as expected

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

[Climbing the leaderboard-Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem?isFullScreen=true)

```
def climbingLeaderboard(ranked, player):
    ranks = []
    ranks.append(1)

    for i in range(1,len(ranked)):
        if ranked[i] == ranked[i - 1]:
            ranks.append(ranks[i-1])
        else:
            ranks.append(ranks[i-1]+1)

    res=[]
    for i in range(len(player)):
        lo=0
        hi=len(ranked)-1
        while(hi>=lo):
            mid=(lo+hi)//2
            if player[i]==ranked[mid]:
                res.append(ranks[mid])
                break
            elif player[i]>ranked[mid]:
                lo=mid+1
            else:
                hi=mid-1
    return res
```

I pre-computed the ranks and used binary search to identify the ranks of the given values in the player array. For one of the sample inputs:
ranked=[100 100 50 40 40 20 10] player=[5 25 50 120] function is returning an empty list, and for another: ranked=[100 90 90 80 75 60] player =[50 65 77 90 102], it returns [2] whereas the expected output is [6 5 4 2 1]. I traced through the program and it seems to be working fine, so I don't understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: What do you mean with "isn't returning anything"? Does it return an empty list? Could you give some example data to test with?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for the confusion. It is returning an empty list. ranked=[ 100 100 50 40 40 20 10] and player=[5 25 50 120] is a sample test case

Answer (score 0):

In `if player[i]==ranked[mid]:` you require that someone already has the same number of points as the player you are currently looking at. But that is not necessarily the case. For example, in the case `ranked=[100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10]` and `player=[5, 25, 50, 120]` the points 5, 25 and 120 do not exist in `ranked`.

Comment: Right, thanks. Could you help me rewrite binary search part to better fit the purposes of this program? I believe we should look for the first number in the ranked array that is greater than the number in player array, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: @easytranslate. Do you really need to do a binary search? I think that the rank of a player is related to the number of different results higher than the player's result. Could you do something from that?

Comment: Yeah, you could start from the end of the ranked array and keep going until you find the first number that is greater than player[i], and find the rank that way.

Comment: I wrote the code for it this way:                                                                  
 j=len(ranked)-1
    res=[]
    for i in range(len(player)):
        while(j>=0):
            if player[i]<ranked[j]:
                res.append(ranks[j]+1)
                break
            j-=1
        if j<0:
             res.append(1)
    return res                                                                                                                                    And it works! But I think binary search should be possible here, but I'm not sure how to implement it

Comment: Let `player_points`  be the points of some player and `player_rank` be the player's rank. Shouldn't then `player_rank = len({ p for p in ranked if p > player_points })`?